# Can Survival/Duration Analysis be used to model recovery from economic recessions?

Tags: survival, econometrics, stata

I am currently completing independent research on how subcontracting affects the ability of the US economy to recover from the 2001 recession. I have my control variables and data for subcontracting from 1997-2017 (by US state).

At this stage, I need to find a functional form to run regressions in Stata. Essentially I want to study how different state's usages of subcontracting affected their length of recovery from the 2001 recession.

Would survival/duration analysis work for this project? Are their other functional regression forms that may make more sense?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: What economic indicator with what value defines when recovery occurs?

Comment: I will be using employment data (quarterly and by state) to estimate when recovery has occurred for each state. I will be following the idea that recovery has occurred when the state economy has regained and/or exceeded peak employment achieved from before the downturn began.

Comment: Isn't that a little bit of a problem since that employment threshold could differ over time and by state. Is there a way you can get around that?

Comment: Considering that peak employment (from before the downturn) will be uniquely observed for each state, I do not think that would be a huge problem. If I were to compare to peak employment of the US (aggregated), that would definitely be a concern. Nonetheless, you raise a very good point and I understand what you are saying. An alternative might be to use GDP per capita as an economic indicator. I believe that this may alleviate these concerns.

Comment: If that problem is solved, do you think that survival analysis could be a feasible regression model? Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: If anyone else has any thoughts, I would greatly appreciate them!